# Проблема с индексацией с помощью ElasticPress в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elasticsearch

Для организации поиска в wordpress по базе ~4 Гб установил elasticsearch и плагин ElasticPress. При включении плагина в логе сайта появляется следующая ошибка и ломается тема сайта. Подскажите, как ее можно исправить?

```
2019/07/16 14:16:35 [error] 1561#1561: *37341 FastCGI sent in stderr: “PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/new/wp-content/plugins/elasticpress/includes/classes/Indexable/Post/QueryIntegration.php:254
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/new/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): ElasticPress\Indexable\Post\QueryIntegration->get_es_posts(NULL, Object(WP_Query))
#1 /var/www/new/wp-includes/plugin.php(251): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /var/www/new/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(2921): apply_filters_ref_array(‘posts_pre_query’, Array)
#3 /var/www/new/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(3404): WP_Query->get_posts()
#4 /var/www/new/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(3513): WP_Query->query(Array)
#5 /var/www/new/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-products.php(171): WP_Query->__construct(Array)
#6 /var/www/new/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-products.php(189): WC_Widget_Products->get_products(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/new/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php(378): WC_Widget_Products->” while reading response header from upstream, client: 108.162.221.173, server: 192.168.1.100, request: “GET /news/medpharm/10-aprelya-budet-predstavlen-publichnyj-rejting-poliklinik-rossii/24/ HTTP/1.1”, upstream: “fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:”, host: “domain.com”
and the design of the site breaks down (it only remains header).
```

Comment: С таким лучше к разрабам плагина: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/elasticpress/

Answer (score 1):

ElasticPress поддерживает только elasticsearch 6.3.2, а у меня была 7.2.0. Пришлось откатится.